# Inner Query Work Flow

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, plsqldeveloper, inner-query

While execute below Query , its executed successfully.

But when execute only (SELECT CREDITDOCUMENTID FROM TBLTPAYMENT    ) it is give error like "00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"".

Doesn't know how its work in oracle 12c database.

```
SELECT *
FROM TBLTCREDITCREDITDOCUMENTREL
WHERE CREDITDOCUMENTID IN
  (SELECT CREDITDOCUMENTID
  FROM TBLTCREDITDOCUMENT
  WHERE CREDITDOCUMENTID IN
    (SELECT CREDITDOCUMENTID FROM TBLTPAYMENT    )
  );
```

Comment: please share the table definition of TBLTCREDITCREDITDOCUMENTREL, TBLTCREDITDOCUMENT and TBLTPAYMENT

Answer (score 2):

An educated guess (and I'm betting on it) would be that your column `CREDITDOCUMENTID` is not a column from the `TBLTPAYMENT` table, but from some other table that is in scope, e.g. in `TBLTCREDITDOCUMENT`. This is easy to check. Try running this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM TBLTCREDITCREDITDOCUMENTREL
WHERE CREDITDOCUMENTID IN
  (SELECT CREDITDOCUMENTID
  FROM TBLTCREDITDOCUMENT
  WHERE CREDITDOCUMENTID IN
    (SELECT TBLTPAYMENT.CREDITDOCUMENTID FROM TBLTPAYMENT)
  );
```

In case of which you qualify the `TBLTPAYMENT.CREDITDOCUMENTID` column. You'll get the same error as when you run the inner-most `SELECT` by itself.

Comment: [Btw, I have discovered an interesting bug in Oracle 12.2.0.1 while researching this problem](https://twitter.com/lukaseder/status/912626775561207808)

Comment: Thanks Lukas for your response, you r right CREDITDOCUMENTID is not a column of  TBLTPAYMENT table, But while execute your provided query it also execute successfully.

Comment: @SamDPatel: Are you *sure*? That's a rather strong contradiction right there.